# setting defaults for zend_form_element (when using the view syntax)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-view

I know I can create a form multi checkbox using `new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox()`. I'm not using this syntax however. I'm using the form view helper syntax in the view, like so:

```
echo $this->formMultiCheckbox('boxes', null, null, $possible_vals_array, null);
```

My question is how do I, using this syntax, add an array for the values that need to be checked by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `$this->formMultiCheckbox()` should be an array of values to have checked.

So if you your `$possible_vals_array` looks like this:

```
$possible_vals_array = array(
    'Value A' => 'Label A',
    'Value B' => 'Label B',
    'Value C' => 'Label C',
);
```

... and say you want to have values A and C checked by default, you'd pass an array like this as the second parameter:

```
$checked_vals_array = array('Value A', 'Value C');
```

So your call to the helper would look like this:

```
echo $this->formMultiCheckbox(
    'boxes', $checked_vals_array, null, $possible_vals_array, null
);
```

Comment: Whoops. I guess the options array should be an associative array of option values and labels. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And when I say "options array", I mean `$possible_vals_array`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was it. I wasn't using an associative array.